# Check if number is equal to 0 or 1

Tags: python, expression

Expected to check if number is equal to 0 or 1.

```
2 == 0 or 1 # Always returns 1
```

Or should I always write?
'''`2 == 0 or 2 == 1`'''

Comment: Yes. you can do this in a number of ways, you can check individually like you did `if a == 2 or a == 1`, or look for it in a list `if  a in [1, 2]` and so on and so forth. But you'll have to check for the values.

Comment: `print(2 == (2 or 1))` use this for check

Comment: Neither equals 2, so why would you need to check it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `in` operator, for example

```
2 in [0, 1]
```

The original code is evaluating whether 2 == 0 (false) or 1 (true).
false or true evaluates to true (1).

Comment: `i` not it is 1

Comment: @ExplooreX thanks error noted and corrected.